# How to click elements in C#

Tags: c#, html

I got a form with a radio button (button with value 3) that I need to select and a submit button that need to be clicked. The problem is I don't know how to select the radio buttons or click the button since it doesn't have a name or id.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<input type="radio" name="chosen" value="3" id="a3">
<input type="radio" name="chosen" value="2" id="a2">
<input type="radio" name="chosen" value="1" id="a1">
<input value="Next" type="submit">
```

Here is the code I've tried for the button (I'm trying to select the button with value 3:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("chosen")[2].InvokeMember("click");
```

but that code won't work and I don't know how to click the button to submit and go on. I need help selecting the radio button and click the submit button. I don't have access to change any of the HTML code.

Comment: If I understand well your question AND if you're using ASP.NET, an alternative could be use a hidden button `<asp:Button` and add javascript code for that once the radiobuttonlist item is pressed/selected, the onclick of the hidden button will execute. Can you add more information about why and how you're using HTML and C#?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding and clicking a button with no ID within html code in WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442882/finding-and-clicking-a-button-with-no-id-within-html-code-in-webbrowser)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you meant by "use C# to click". Because basically, the element is displayed and interact in browsers (Chrome, FireFox). And C# is for processing http requests in server (IIS).

So to select/click some html element, you can use jQuery such as

```
$('input[value="3"]').click();
```

Comment: Inside a .net desktop apps, you can have a webrowser element, from there you can interact with the DOM. That is what Patric is attempting here. As such jQuery (or javasctipt) is not really of use in this case

Comment: @JonP: You CAN use javascript and even jQuery in WebBrowser, if you inject the code.

Comment: @PoulBak, true, I over simplified my comment... should really be "jQuery/javascript, alone, is not really of use in this case"